# Does SQL Server Agent capture errors resulting from an SSIS package run?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SQL Server Agent job set up to execute a SSIS package once a day.  The history log for that Job has been reporting success every day, but I don't know if it's simply telling me that it was successful in **launching the package**, or if the package tasks actually completed without error.

Would the Job history log tell me if something went wrong *while the package was running its tasks*, or is there another error report I'd need to look for to see the details of the package run.

Comment: Yes you'd see a red x (unless you specifically configured your job to not return errors). You should check the logs anyway

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, Nick.

Comment: do you log on sysssislog??

Comment: No I don't  Does this matter?

Answer (score -1):

Per Nick.McDermaid:

"Yes you'd see a red x (unless you specifically configured your job to not return errors). You should check the logs anyway."